# facebook api /me/events/not_replied

Tags: facebook, api

I'm trying to get the events/not_replied from me, but all I get is an empty array....

I've tried those:

```
$facebook->api('/me/events/not_replied','GET');
```

and

```
$facebook->api('/me/events/not_replied');
```

and

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/events/not_replied?access_token='.$access_token;

$string = file_get_contents($url);
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
```

and etc...

none works. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request the "user_events" permission.